# creating https connection in android

Tags: android, https

After lot of research by going through various forums on stackoverflow and blogs like antonie,vipul,i am unbale to still resolve this error "*no peer certificate*".

The code I used is exactly like given on this [blog entry](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/)

But still, I am getting an exception. I have also created `.bks` file and using it in the code. Please don't mark it as a duplicate and don't answer me to how to trust all certificates because I have already studied that

I have used this code:

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    final Context context;

    public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
        // to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cacer);
           // FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("key.bks"));

            try {

                 trusted.load(in, "govill".toCharArray());
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Also provide the password of the keystore
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
            // for the verification of the server certificate.
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
            // Hostname verification from certificate
            // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the server to which you want to connect configured for SSL? Does he have a valid certificate? Also, and probably most importantly, are you using self-signed certificates and do you want the server to authenticate to the user and vice versa or just the first case?

Answer (score -1):

```
public String SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException  {


            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);


            // Set HTTP parameters
            /*StringEntity se;
            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());*/
            jsonObjSend.length();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(jsonObjSend.length());
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonObjSend.toString()));
           // Log.i("jsonObjSend.toString()","jsonObjSend.toString()"+jsonObjSend.toString());

            Log.i("HTTPPOST","URL: "+URL);
            Log.i("HTTPPOST","Request: "+jsonObjSend.toString());
            UrlEncodedFormEntity en=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
            en.getContent();
            httpPostRequest.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(600000));
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(en);
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");
            Log.i(TAG, httpPostRequest.getRequestLine().getProtocolVersion().toString());
            responses = convertEntityToString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            Log.i("HTTPPOST","Responce: "+responses);
            Log.i("HTTPPOST","******************");
            //Log.i("Encoding",response.getEntity().getContentEncoding().getName());

        return responses;
    }
```

Comment: What has that answer got to do with OP's question? -1

Comment: eric-tobias,i am using this code to call for "https://demo.yoursuppliernetwork.com" Yes i want that server should authenticate the user through username and password i am sending to it